# chart object off screen

Tags: excel, vba, charts, office-interop

I'm using c# calling vba macro to draw chart in excel, 8 charts in a worksheet, some of them will be off screen. Excel will draw the charts off(out of) screen at the center of screen, then the charts will be placed at the correct positions after I scroll down the work sheet.[image]

I don't want to see the chart being placed at the center of worksheet(although it can be placed back to correct position when I scroll down the worksheet), What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Does scrolling help? If so, make the VBA do that scrolling

Comment: I added "ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 100" in my macro, but an error pop up with "Unable to get the scrollRow property for window class", Do you know why? I'm using office 2003

Comment: Did you google?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I have to ask: Can you honestly read those charts? the false 3D and the extreme angle make them impossible to interpret, where plain old 2D column charts (with a bunch of code to remove the ugly default Excel 2003 formatting) would be a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
Sub test()
Sheet1.Activate
    With ActiveWindow
        .ScrollColumn = 16
        .ScrollRow = 20
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't bothered to post the code that's inserting the charts. In VBA, the syntax is like this:

```
Dim cht As Chart

Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(ChartType, Left, Top, Width, Height).Chart
```

ChartType is the constant corresponding to the chart type you're creating, Left and Top are the distance from the top left corner of the sheet to the top left corner of the chart in points, and Width and Height are the dimensions of the chart in points.

So put the coordinates into the AddChart function as you insert the chart, rather than move and size the chart after it's been drawn.